# How to use CSS to make an input fields behaves like a button click?

Tags: jquery, html, css

Currently I need to make an input field to change value inside by clicking on it. I want to use CSS to make the field looks more like a button when it haven't been clicked. Is there any sample CSS I could follow?  Here is my sample code:         https://jsfiddle.net/TasteMyBiceps/sxw29n38/. Thank you!

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('#inp').prop('readonly','true');

 $('#inp').click(function(){
   if($(this).val()==""){
   $(this).val("Yes");
    }
    else{
     $(this).val("");
    }
    
    $(this).toggleClass('inputClick');
  });
});
```

```css
#inp {
  width: 40px;
  text-align: center;
}

.inputClick {
    background: #D8D8D8;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.1/jquery.js"></script>

<input id="inp" type=text />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `border-style` set to `outset`

```
input { 
  background:#eee;
  border-style:outset;
}
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#inp').prop('readonly', 'true');

  $('#inp').click(function() {
    if ($(this).val() == "") {
      $(this).val("Yes");
    } else {
      $(this).val("");
    }

    $(this).toggleClass('inputClick');
  });
});
```

```css
input { 
  background:#eee;
  border-style:outset;
}

#inp {
  width: 40px;
  text-align: center;
}
.inputClick {
  background: #D8D8D8;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.1/jquery.js"></script>

<input id="inp" type=text />
```

Comment: Yeah, That's exactly what I need

Answer (score 0):

Try with:

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     $('#inp').attr('readonly','true');

    $('#inp').click(function(){
    if($(this).val()==""){
        $(this).val("Yes");
    }
    else{
       $(this).val("");
    }

   $(this).toggleClass('inputClick');
});});
```

CSS:

```
.inputClick {
   background: #D8D8D8;
   border: 1px solid #fff;
   border-radius: 4px;
   padding: 4px;
   cursor: pointer;
  }
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer

Answer (score 0):

You can change the input type to button

---

```js
    $(this).attr('type','button');
```

Comment: I currently creating a survey and a platform called "Confirmit". The element there is limited to input.

Answer (score 0):

you can try like this one. check on snippet.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('#inp').prop('readonly','true');

 $('#inp').click(function(){
   if($(this).val()==""){
   $(this).val("Yes");
    }
    else{
     $(this).val("");
    }
    $(this).toggleClass('inputClick');
  });
});
```

```css
#inp {
  min-width: 40px;
  text-align: center;
}

.inputClick {
  background: #3498db;
  -webkit-border-radius: 28px;
  -moz-border-radius: 28px;
  border-radius: 28px;
  font-family: Arial;
  color: #ffffff;
  text-decoration: none;
  border:none;
  transition: background 0.4s;
  cursor: pointer;
  }
  .inputClick:hover{
     background: #3cb0fd;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="inp" type=text />
```

Comment: Thank you! fancy button. :)